# Change in Context doesn't show in Consumer element

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have set a context which has fields updated by an API call:

```
export const CharacterContext = React.createContext()

export class CharacterProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            text: "test, test",
            name: "no-name",
            id: "999",
            currStamina: 0,
            abilities: {
                "bra": 0,
                "agi": 0,
                "int": 0,
                "cun": 0,
                "will": 0,
                "pre": 0
            },

            skills: [],
            characters: [],
            getCharacter: this.getCharacter,
        }
    }

    getCharacter = (id) => {
        CharacterDataService.getCharacterById(id)
            .then(
                response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        name: response.data.username,
                        maxStamina: response.data.stamina,
                        currStamina: response.data.stamina,
                        id: response.data.id,
                        abilities: response.data.abilities,
                        skills: response.data.skills
                    });
                }
            );
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <CharacterContext.Provider
                value={this.state}>
               {
                   this.props.children
               }
            </CharacterContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}


export const CharacterConsumer = CharacterContext.Consumer
```

Another element has set Provider and Consumer inside for the purpose of testing. It receives the state from the provider, but even though the element is rendered AFTER context update (through a Router), it shows original values (abilities set to 0 etc...).

```
export default class Edit extends React.Component {
    static contextType = CharacterContext;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CharacterProvider>
                <CharacterConsumer>
                    {({text, currStamina}) => (
                        <p>{text} : {currStamina}</p>
                    )}
                </CharacterConsumer>
                <Abilities/>
            </CharacterProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Why does the values in context update by the API call but the consumer element still shows the original values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the problem was in nesting consumer element directly under the provider. What didn't work:

```
render() {
        return (
            <CharacterProvider>
                <CharacterConsumer>
                    {({text, currStamina}) => (
                        <p>{text} : {currStamina}</p>
                    )}
                </CharacterConsumer>
                <Abilities/>
            </CharacterProvider>
        )
    }
```

This didn't work (change in the Provider didn't propagate to the consumer). As soon as I moved the Provider to parent element, the consumer was update with every change of the provider.

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CharacterConsumer>
                    {({text, currStamina}) => (
                        <p>{text} : {currStamina}</p>
                    )}
                </CharacterConsumer>
                </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's a router problem. 
Can you check if you `<Link />` components are rendered outside of the router context. If is rendered outside the Router, meaning the Links will fallback to the default value passed to `createContext`.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. I set default values in the context. Then I use an API call to setState new values from the API. I see that values changed in the context. Yet when I open an consumer element through router (clicking on the Link element) I do not see the new values, but the default ones. Is my problem clearer now?

Comment: Hi @Faire, sorry I haven't understood well your question at the beginning. So on my opinion is for some reason the is a router problem. I'll update my answer.

Comment: First thanks for taking time to look at my problem!

And second: after some toying it seems that if I render Provider element in parent element (say App.js) and Customer element in the child element (say Edit element, rendered by the App.js) the consumer gets the updated information. 

But when I render both Provider and Customer elements in the Edit element, the change in the Provider doesn't propagate. So this doesn't work:

<CharacterProvider>
                <CharacterConsumer>
                        ....
                </CharacterConsumer>
             </CharacterProvider>

Comment: so it seems that the context it's not propagation as it should. the only way that I can point you is for documentation. sorry, I hope you sort it out.   [docs context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)